# How to organize source control for multiple projects depending on common projects in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control

I am just to start a new big sp 2013 project, I am studying different ways to organize the vs structure and one of the ways I liked is to separate for example webparts in different solutions:

http://bitofthought.blogspot.in/2012/05/visual-studio-sharepoint-solution.html

Also, some libraries will be common to all projects.

The thing that is turning me crazy is that we will use team foundation server, and in tfs each project has its own work items and its work source control repository.

Lets say that I make a HR application, then I create the HR tfs project with backlog items, tasks, bugs, etc.

But, what about common projects outside HR, lets say that HR uses 3 webpart projects, and one common library to all projects. How would you organize these "external" or "common" projects?

Should I create a tfs project also for every single one of them? or one for all but without workitems, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For groups that do a lot of small projects, sometimes it's best to have a TFS project for the Team, and not multiple projects per development project. For example, perhaps you're using scrum, and your backlog has items from HR and other groups. But, even though there are different "projects" with different deadlines and even different technologies, it's treated as one backlog. So, there's one daily scrum meeting where all of the smaller projects are discussed. And, there's one sprint, where folks spend time working on pieces of different projects. And, of course, this means that there is one TFS project to manage work items and such.